# Show function at controller not getting value from index

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I really get here to bother you only when I can't find an answer.
I don't know Why I get a null at show function at productoservicioevento. It's the same code that I use at grupo and there I get the id...

index at module productoservicioevento

```
@foreach($productoservicioeventos as $productoservicioevento)
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="/gymmgr/public/productoservicioeventos/{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}">{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}</a>></td>
                <!--<td> <a href="/gymmgr/public/productoservicioeventos/{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}">{{ $productoservicioevento->strConcepto }}</a>></td>-->
        <td>{{ $productoservicioevento->dcmPrecio }}</td>
        <td>{{ $productoservicioevento->evento->strNombreEvento }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

show function at productoservicioeventocontroller

```
public function show(ProductoServicioEvento $productoServicioEvento)
{
    //
    //$productoServicioEvento = ProductoServicioEvento::all();
    dd($productoServicioEvento);
    dd($productoServicioEvento->idProductoServicioEvento);
    $productoServicioEvento = ProductoServicioEvento::find($productoServicioEvento->idProductoServicioEvento);
```

I get null when click at index

[image]

[image]

The module from productoservicioevento was actually copied from

index at grupo

```
@foreach($productoservicioeventos as $productoservicioevento)
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="/gymmgr/public/productoservicioeventos/{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}">{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}</a>></td>
                <!--<td> <a href="/gymmgr/public/productoservicioeventos/{{ $productoservicioevento->idProductoServicioEvento }}">{{ $productoservicioevento->strConcepto }}</a>></td>-->
        <td>{{ $productoservicioevento->dcmPrecio }}</td>
        <td>{{ $productoservicioevento->evento->strNombreEvento }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Everything is Ok at gruposcontroller, show function

```
public function show(grupo $grupo)
{
    //
    dd($grupo);
    $grupo = grupo::find($grupo->idGrupo);
```

[image]

Everything goes fine there...

[image]

Te routes, Totally basic.

```
    Route::resource('lockers','LockersController');
    Route::resource('escuelas','EscuelasController');
    Route::resource('grupos','GruposController');
    Route::resource('productoservicioeventos','ProductoServicioEventosController');
    Route::resource('horarioperiodicos','HorarioPeriodicosController');
    Route::resource('eventos','EventosController');
```

I changed this.

```
public function show(ProductoServicioEvento $productoServicioEvento)
{
    //
    //$productoServicioEvento = ProductoServicioEvento::all();
    dd($productoServicioEvento);
    dd($productoServicioEvento->idProductoServicioEvento);
    $productoServicioEvento = ProductoServicioEvento::find($productoServicioEvento->idProductoServicioEvento);
```

For this

```
public function show( $producto)
{
    //

    //dd($producto);
    /*dd($productoServicioEvento->idProductoServicioEvento);*/
    $productoServicioEvento = null;
    $productoServicioEvento = ProductoServicioEvento::find($producto);
```

Now I'm able to work but don't know the reason why I  had to change model to id...

So I'm totally stuck, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the null value, exactly?

Comment: As you can see at the first black screen (productoservicioevento), the object is empty, nothing arrived from index to the controller, so any property is null. The former, even when it's a copy from grupo. The second black screen shows 3 elements in the array. The strange thing is that the first module is a copy from the second one, the things that change are the names of the objects.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing [implicit/explicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#implicit-binding) with regular `id` parameter pass through route. You should choose one of both methods.

Comment: What else could be? cause the mechanics is exactly the same for grupo. It's as if the object wouldn't be populated. Seems like is not detecting what kind of model I'm passing to but, index works fine and the default calling when I click the ID should be to  the show method, isn't it.

Comment: Can you add the routes for those controllers?

Comment: Yes, I already did that, at the end of the body of the post. Now I'm able to keep going but I'm confused. Why  the mechanics always worked as I used to and now I had to change from model to id as parameter for the show function. Suppose that it is because impicit/explicit that you menctioned before, I'm not able to detect where I did the changes for that. Is there a resource where I can find a simpler answer, for those of us being newbies.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding explains it very well. Check against your code and you will find it.

Comment: What will happend when I implemment the update function if everything works like it did this time, that receives the request, I can't replace that to...